# How do I fill the remaining portions in the button?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, paint

I have been trying the round button but there is a problem here. Currently I am getting a button like this :

[image]

What I want to do is fill the remaining portions in the button square. How do I do this ? This is the code that painted this button.

```java
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

class Tester extends JButton {

        public Tester(String label) {
            super(label);
            setContentAreaFilled(false);
            Dimension size = this.getPreferredSize();
            size.width = size.height = Math.max(size.width,size.height);
            this.setPreferredSize(size);

        }

        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {System.out.println("Inside the paintComponent method");
            if (getModel().isArmed()) {
                g.setColor(Color.lightGray);
            } else {
                g.setColor(getBackground());
            }
            g.fillOval(0,0,getSize().width-1,getSize().height-1);
            System.out.println(getSize().width);
            System.out.println(getSize().height);
            super.paintComponent(g);
        }


        public static void main(String args[]) {
            JFrame fr = new JFrame();
            JPanel p = new JPanel();
            JButton button = new Tester("Click Me !");
            button.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
            p.add(button);
            fr.add(p);
            fr.setVisible(true);
            fr.setSize(400,400);    
            fr.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        }
}
```

How do I fill the remaining portions in the button ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just use the `fillrect()` method to fill the remaining portion before you call `fillOval()`

```
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        System.out.println("Inside the paintComponent method");
        g.setColor(Color.red); // here
        g.fillRect(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight()); //here

        if (getModel().isArmed()) {
            g.setColor(Color.lightGray);
        } else {
            g.setColor(getBackground());
        }

        g.fillOval(0, 0, getSize().width - 1, getSize().height - 1);
        System.out.println(getSize().width);
        System.out.println(getSize().height);
        super.paintComponent(g);
    }
```

Doing like above I'll get

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: This answered the question but if I do this the borders are still visible even if I set the background color of the panel equal to the color of the rectangle..So !

Comment: You need to set the border to clear the border. I'm not sure this is the right way. But using `setBorder(null);` cleared the border.

Comment: Though it works fine..I am not clear why do you say ,_"I am not sure this is the right way"_

Comment: I saw some overriding the `paintBorder` method . How is it different from the method you just described ?

Comment: @saplingPro I mean to say that setting anything null is a special case as I learnt it from my seniors. Any way I was not aware of paintBorder honestly. I'll look at it. thanks.

Comment: @saplingPro I saw @MadProgrammer comment. Instead of using `setBorder(null)` its better if we use `setBorderPainted(false);`. Thanks to him.

Answer (score 2):

Simply use something like `Graphics#fillRect` to fill a rectangular area

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    System.out.println("Inside the paintComponent method");
    // Or what ever background color you want...
    g.setColor(Color.RED);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
    if (getModel().isArmed()) {
        g.setColor(Color.lightGray);
    } else {
        g.setColor(getBackground());
    }
    g.fillOval(0,0,getSize().width-1,getSize().height-1);
    System.out.println(getSize().width);
    System.out.println(getSize().height);
    super.paintComponent(g);
}
```

Comment: Though this answers my question, the borders are still visible if I set the color of the rectangle = background color of the panel. How can I avoid this ?

Comment: Try using [JButton#setBorderPainted](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setBorderPainted(boolean)) and setting it to false

Comment: Is it the same thing as setting `setBorder(null)` ?